# How to remove an element from a variable using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove 2nd occurrence of th element from below variable

```
var t1= 
'<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th>first</th>
            <th>second</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
</table>';
```

I tried doing

```
$(t1).find('thead').children().slice(2).detach();
```

It doesn't work.

I also tried below

```
var ndx = 2;

$(t1).find('thead').remove(":nth-child(" + ndx + ")");
```

It also doesn't work.

I know it shouldn't be that complicated. Could someone help me out how to remove element using jQuery

Thanks

Comment: remove 2 occurrence of what?

Comment: what do you trying to do ? do you want to remove second row data which came from database ? if yes it came from database you should get the id first then throw to you php to execute delete data from database, hope this helps

Comment: $("table th:nth-child(2)").remove();

use it like this

Comment: use  $(t1).find('th').slice(2).detach();